# Type Error Importing GeoJSON file in a Typescript React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to import a GeoJSON file to map region in a Leaflet map using React-Leaflet. I started the project using create-react-app. However, when I try to use the data in the GeoJSON component, I receive an error indicating the JSON type is not assignable to type GeoJsonObject.

```
TS2322: Type '{ type: string; features: ({ type: string; geometry: { type: string; coordinates: number[][][][]; }; properties: { BCR: number; BCRN
AME: string; Label: string; }; } | { type: string; geometry: { type: string; coordinates: number[][][]; }; properties: { ...; }; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'GeoJsonObject'.
```

```typescript
...
import bar from './../../data/bar.json'

export const Page = () => {
    return(
        <main>
            <MapContainer center={[45, -95]} zoom={3}>
                <TileLayer
                    ...
                />
                <GeoJSON data={bar} />
            </MapContainer>
        </main>
    )
}
```

I have tried installing geojson and @types/geojson using npm, but that didn't help. However, inspired by [this comment](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/21794#issuecomment-347522302), I downgraded the version of @types/geojson to 1.0.6. This let the app run, but my IDE is still complaining about a type error:

```
TS2741: Property  type  is missing in type  {}  but required in type  GeoJsonObject 
index.d.ts(48, 5):  type  is declared here.
GeoJSON.d.ts(7, 5): The expected type comes from property  data  which is declared here on type
IntrinsicAttributes & GeoJSONProps & RefAttributes<GeoJSON<any, Geometry>>
```

Is there a way to define the type of the imported JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

TypeScript expects the GeoJSON data to conform to the GeoJsonObject type.

### Solution

1. Create a new type MyGeoJsonType that extends GeoJsonObject and
   includes specific properties expected in your GeoJSON data.
2. import Feature, Geometry, and GeoJsonObject types from the geojson module.
3. Use the new type MyGeoJsonType for the geoJsonData variable, which holds your GeoJSON data.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';
import { Feature, Geometry, GeoJsonObject } from 'geojson'; // Import GeoJSON types

import bar from './../../data/bar.json';

type MyGeoJsonType = GeoJsonObject & {
  features: Feature<Geometry, { BCR: number; BCRNAME: string; Label: string }>[];
};

export const Page = () => {
  const geoJsonData: MyGeoJsonType = bar;

  return (
    <main>
      <MapContainer center={[45, -95]} zoom={3}>
        <TileLayer
          // ...other props
        />
        <GeoJSON data={geoJsonData} />
      </MapContainer>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Make sure to adjust the type definition based on the structure of your actual GeoJSON data. This should help TypeScript recognize the GeoJSON type correctly and resolve the issue you're facing.

### Note to Isaa:

I see you're a new contributor, welcome! Make sure to check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on what to do with answers to your questions!

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by casting the GeoJSON object within the  component.

```
<GeoJSON data={BCRData as GeoJsonObject} />
```